# Downsampling an image by 2, OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

guys. Just for you know, I'm new to this environment, so if I do something wrong, feel free to warn me.

So, I was trying to create a basic algorithm for downsampling an image by an ancient technique. I'm new to OpenCV as well.

```
#include "opencv2/core/utility.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void filter2(const Mat &image, Mat &out)
{
    // convert and split
    Mat imgf;
    image.convertTo(imgf, CV_32F, 1.0 / 255.0);
    Mat chn[3];
    split(imgf, chn);
    Mat newchn[3];  
    // Resampling by 2
    for (int dim = 0; dim < 3; dim++) {
        Mat dummy2;
        Mat dummy = chn[dim];
        for (int i = 0; i < chn[dim].rows/2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < chn[dim].cols/2; j++) {             
                dummy2.at<double>(i,j) = dummy.at<double>(i*2,j*2);         
            }
        }
        dummy2 = newchn[dim];
    }
    // merge and convert
    merge(newchn, 3, imgf);
    imgf.convertTo(out, CV_8U, 255.0);
}

int main(int agra, char** argv) {
    String fn = "eva_green.png";
    if (agra > 1) fn = argv[1];
    Mat image = imread(fn);
    if (image.empty())
    {
        cerr << "No image";
        return 1;
    }
    Mat result;
    filter2(image, result);
    imshow("org", image);
    imshow("res", result);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;

}
```

The "filter2" function does the job. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: `CV_32F` is `float`, not `double`. |  `dummy2` is empty, and you're trying to access its elements. | split/merge is unnecessary - you can access whole pixels as type `Vec3f`. | Conversion to floating point seems unnecessary as well, you never do any calculations with the intensities and convert back at the end.

Comment: Why not just use the opencv [https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d4/d1f/tutorial_pyramids.html] pyrdown  function

Comment: For example [here](https://pastebin.com/0B3sbdcR) is a version of your function that avoids the unnecessary steps.

Comment: @ZararYounis i know that function, just i m trying to get warmer on c++, normally i m matlab guy

Comment: @DanMašek ty for ur contribution Dan, i ll try another way

Comment: @DanMašek hmm, i ll go for this, i didnt know Vec3f class either...